# Django snapshot upload and face recognize with opencv

Tags: javascript, django, opencv, facial-identification, python

I'm trying take snapshot with getUserMedia() and recognize face using opencv-python. I only get encoded image from user media and can't open it with opencv. I'm using django 2.2 as backend server

Comment: Please add some code showing how you tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Please read this forum's help section on how to ask a good question.